# Internet and Server Connection and Communication

Tags: c#, security

I am working on a .NET-based application, using C#. I've been searching the web for weeks and months without luck, and I am unable to find an example or a solution or a recommended approach.

What I want to do is:

Make an application that connects to a Server (over the Internet) and downloads 
 information from a database, like for example: An antivirus connecting to a server and
 downloading virus signature files.

How can I implement a stable and safe connection to a web-server?

Comment: when you stay "stable and safe connection", do you mean an always established connection? If yes then you should use secured TCP Sockets.

Comment: Please don't use "C#:". Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 0):

I can Suggest you,
1st use web service that gives data as steam to your application
2nd use remote database, and store-fetch from it as you do when it's `localhost`

Comment: So I should use the SOAP approach? Can you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: Why the hel SOPA came in Game??

Comment: Hi SlimGG, I've seen some videos where SOAP was used combined with C#, to be more exact, PHP and C#. Since C# => direct access => MySQL on a server isn't a safe approach.

Comment: Ohk, ..i never go for that, Better you make web service, using WCF and have connection between your App and Server.

Comment: Does WCF work on a Linux Server? I think it doesn't but maybe you have a better answer.

Comment: Oke, you have Linux, than make something Called MonoDevelop IDE which will help you to make web service using ASP.net on Linux too. Else you can choose PHP or Java , depending upon your area of mastery.

Comment: Slim, I've heard about the Mono IDE and C#, but I was wondering if C# could invoke PHP code to perform authentication to the database?

Comment: why you want php to do auth, u can do it via C# only, else you can Http classes to play around with web [php]

Comment: I need to select a safe way to access the database and download information about applications.

Comment: if you go down the WCF route, it is interoperable with any language/platform as long as the language/platform you use supports webservices (ie: soap/rest) and that you stay aways from microsoft specific bindings, which means you will use either BasicHTTP, WebHTTP or WSHttp bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file from a website using the WebClient class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx

Comment: Hi ZippyV, yes, I know about that class, I've used it I do not have issues with that. I want my application to be able to upload/download information about applications, for example: Whitelist and Blacklist. Two lists with details about third-party apps, e.g. Publisher, Application version, Application Name, Application ID, Support website etc.

Comment: Look into odata: http://www.odata.org/ On the libraries page you will find what to use for your .net client app and php libraries for the server side.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a good answer in many cases when communication is required between two parties and selected technology is .NET.

Sample below describes how you can download file.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

It loads data from `Stream` so it can be easily adapted for getting data from database.

With WCF you can postpone Security and Transport decisions. You may implement `basicHttpBinding` and make sure that everything is working as expected and switch to TCP and Secure channel just by updating config files.

Logic for discovering what file is good for you should be implemented as separate methods. And  again you can you SOAP or REST/Web bindings for your business functions and TCP or P2P for files download.